# What is the meaning of this Midrash about Eve in the Garden?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, eve-chava

In the [Zohar Hadash 91D](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.3.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Zohar_Chadash%2C_Midrash_HaNe%27elam_Al_Eichah.26-27&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en), Midrash Ha-Ne-elam on Ekhah, in reference to Eve and the serpent (who is described as female), it states:

> "קָרֵיב הַהוּא נָחָשׁ לְגַבֵּי אִיתְּתָא, דְּדַעְתָּא קַלָּה מִן הָאִישׁ.
> מִכָּאן דְּאִתְּתָא לָא אִתְפַּתַּת, אֶלָּא בְּאִתְּתָא אָחֳרָא."
> "a woman can only be seduced by another woman"

The Zohar Hadash 69a brings a similar statement.

What are the Rabbinic explanations on this concept? Whether Zohar commentaries specifically, or, if similar teachings are brought from earlier midrashim, those are also relevant to the question. I am interested in any and all levels of (kosher) meaning of the teaching.

Comment: If there is anyone reading who gets uncomfortable about Zohar questions, let me stress that a Zohar Hadash excerpt just happens to be the first place I became aware of the concept, and I'm not sure if it was recorded anywhere earlier or if it was first recorded in Zohar Hadash. But to be clear, I am interested in learning the teaching in general, not limited to Zohar Hadash. If I had read it first in a Rashi's commentary on Tanach I would ask about it just the same (this is not to imply that it is in Rashi's commentary. It isn't, to my recollection. Just a hypothetical example).

Comment: Why would anyone gets uncomfortable with Zohar questions?

Comment: @Shmuel I know where you're coming from. The reason I wrote the comment is, for starters, I know first hand not every Jew agrees with Kabbalah in general. Then even Jews who accept Kabbalah, maybe some still believe in age requirements, while others think it should only be learned in Hebrew.

Honestly I dont really know. I just know when I asked about learning the different incarnations in english in Torah from Sha'ar Gilgulim, some didnt believe that was appropriate (in english), even tho I learned later that there is an english summary already online.

Comment: @Shmuel So I think many have different opinions about how Torah should be taught and learned, including how the internet should be used for Torah. I'm not qualified at all to know which ways are right and which aren't. I just know what I feel is relevant to my life and my learning, and what I want to learn to progress, and so I ask about that and hope people will help me learn what I ask about over the communication tools that we have available (the internet). But how it should work on a general level, that's above my paygrade.

Comment: As far as my knowledge on this subject goes, the Zohar is teaching us here that the serpent was a "female", e.g. the female-part of the Satan. The Zohar refers to the female serpent when saying "a woman can only be seduced by another woman". It is the "serpent" who seduces in this world so to say.

Comment: Thanks for the comment (and the edit) Shmuel. My comprehension of it meaning the serpent is female, and it meaning Eve was seduced by the serpent, is the same as that. The answers I'm still looking for are any other meanings of the verse in general, and specifically why it's women who can only be seduced by women. If it just meant the serpent was female and the serpent seduces, it should have said "men and women can only be seduced by a woman," instead of specifying "a woman" can only be seduced by another woman.

Comment: I think that's daf 111a, near the bottom https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%90

Comment: If you look at the source you link to, it indicates that this is dealing with the subject of similarities in words & names in Hebrew. The name of G-d associated with wife is צלמו. This name derives from 5 dimensional/aspects (in contrast to the 3 dimensional form associated with אלהים) which in the context of Hebrew letters has a dual connotation of Kindness & Judgement. The Nachash, which is also this dual principle, inclines toward Judgement by adding the letter Tav, which can be either for life or for death, to צלמו resulting in צלמות, the Shadow of Death.

Comment: Thanks Yaacov. Maybe it's the limited english translations available, but every midrash I've read about the Nachash is focused only on the evil aspect, the evil serpent that defiled Eve etc etc. There are midrashim about how Yaakov and Moshiach are holy serpents, but what sources say the Nachash of Bereshit refers to them, or to a holy Nachash in general? 

Thats my main follow up other than a shorter one. You mentioned Tav is added to Nachash when it is inclined toward Judgement. What letter is added when it inclines towards Kindness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate meaning seems to be:
**The woman (Adam's woman) was only seduced by that other woman (the Serpent as the S-M's mate and vehicle/agent).**

This whole Midrash seems be mirroring Lam. 1:1, upside-down, to Gen. 2-3. That is, just as HK"BH bestowed Adam with Menuchah, teaching him the Chokhmah and the Torah -- just the opposite, the S"M through the Serpent posed "Af-Ki" etc" - wrath and doubt - and poisonous clever talk, until he seduced her away from the Miswah and polluted her with impurity.

Starting from the beginning of the Tannaim's perush:

Zohar Chadash 110b - is the correct page.

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9_(%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%93)/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94

(Lam. 1:1) "How she sits alone" [possibly also: How did the city get captive? BaDaD - Beit - By two mediums (as the Tannaim explain); DaD - breast, female; also Daleit, door (mouth), and in Aramaic "has-not," is Malkhut, speech, also perhaps alluding to a square Mem when joined together] – R' Chaninai and Rabbanan opened their lesson: Read [it] of Adam haRishon (Gen. 2), "And H' Elohim took eth-ha-Adam and put him in Gan Eden" etc. By what did he take him? R' Chaninai said, He took him with words, as it says, (Lev. 8), "Take et-Aharon." But Rabbanan said, "By Ruach (spirit), as it says (2 Kings 2), "Today H' takes your master from above your head."

אֵיכָה יָשְׁבָה בָדָד, ר' חֲנִינָאי וְרַבָּנָן פָּתְחֵי קְרָא בְּאָדָם הָרִאשׁוֹן. (בראשית, ב) וַיִּקַּח ה' אֱלֹהִים אֶת הָאָדָם וַיַּנִּיחֵהוּ בְגַן עֵדֶן וְגו'. וַיִּקַּח, בַּמֶּה לְקָחוֹ. ר' חֲנִינָאי אָמַר, לְקָחוֹ בִּדְבָרִים. כמה דאת אמר (ויקרא, ח) קַח אֶת אַהֲרֹן. וְרַבָּנָן אָמְרוּ, לְקָחוֹ בְּרוּחַ. כמה דאת אמר, (מלכים ב, ב) הַיּוֹם ה' לֹקֵחַ אֶת אֲדֹנֶיךָ מֵעַל רֹאשֶׁךָ.

"And placed him (NChH) in Gan Eden" – so that he may have meNuChaH/serenity, knowing and recognizing the Chokhmah (Kabbalah) and the Torah. For Rabbi Chaninai said, "The Holy Blessed One taught the Torah to Adam," behold it's the scripture (Job. 28:28), "Then did He see it and tell it … And He said to Adam…"  And the Ministering Angels were praising Him -

וַיַּנִּיחֵהוּ בְגַן עֵדֶן, כְּדֵי לִהְיוֹת לוֹ מְנוּחָה, לָדַעַת וּלְהַכִּיר הַחָכְמָה וְהַתּוֹרָה. דְּאָמַר רִבִּי חֲנִינָאי, הַתּוֹרָה לִימְדָהּ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לָאָדָם. הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב, (איוב, כח) אָז רָאָהּ וַיְסַפְּרָהּ וְגו', וַיֹּאמֶר לָאָדָם. וְהָיוּ מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁרֵת מְקַלְסִין לְפָנָיו.

Until S-M in heaven saw, and was jealous of him, and descended from heaven like in the image of a shadow, upon the Serpent. The Serpent appeared, and with the shadow upon it, [the S-M being] its power and strength.

עַד שֶׁרָאָה סמא"ל בַּשָּׁמַיִם, וְנִתְקַנֵּא בּוֹ, וְיָרַד מִן הַשָּׁמַיִם כִּדְמוּת צֵל עַל נָחָשׁ. הַנָּחָשׁ נִרְאָה, וְהַצֵּל עָלָיו, תָּקְפָא וְחֵילָא דִילֵיהּ.

… The Serpent approached the woman, for her Daat is lighter than the Ish's [more easily persuaded]. **From here (we learn) the woman was only seduced by the other "woman"** [In Tikunei Zohar it's mentioned the Serpent is the S-M's female mate] (Gen. 3) "And he said to the woman, Af (Even?, also Anger) did God say" – immediately he started with "Af." From here we learn that from the beginning of a person's words one can recognize who he is. So he opened with "Af" – revealing who he is.

קָרֵיב הַהוּא נָחָשׁ לְגַבֵּי אִיתְּתָא, דְּדַעְתָּא קַלָּה מִן הָאִישׁ. מִכָּאן דְּאִתְּתָא לָא אִתְפַּתַּת, אֶלָּא בְּאִתְּתָא אָחֳרָא. (בראשית, ג) וַיֹּאמֶר אֶל הָאִשָּׁה אַף כִּי אָמַר אֱלֹהִים, מִיָּד פָּתַח בְּאַף. מֵהָכָא, דְּבִתְחִלַּת דְּבָרָיו שֶׁל אָדָם נִיכָּר מִי הוּא. כָּךְ הוּא פָּתַח בְּאַף, לְהוֹדִיעַ מִי הוּא.

He raised this sign [Af?], whether she accepts or not. He pulled her with words [speech is Malkhut, female] until she opened with the Ot (letter/sign) Mem and said, "Mi-kol, From all the trees of the Gan we may eat-eat." Immediately the Serpent picked up the Ot (letter), and put her on his left arm, and was waiting for a Waw Taw from her mouth so that MWT (death) would be before them (spelled out).

נָטַל סִימָן זֶה, אִם תְּקַבֵּל, אִם לֹא תְקַבֵּל. וְהִמְשִׁיכָהּ בִּדְבָרִים, עַד שֶׁפָּתְחָה בְּאוֹת מ"ם, וְאָמְרָה מִכָּל עֵץ הַגָּן אָכֹל נֹאכֵל. מִיָּד נָטַל הַנָּחָשׁ הָאוֹת, וַיָּשֶׂם אוֹתָהּ עַל זְרוֹעוֹ הַשְּׂמָאלִית, וְהָיָה מַמְתִּין עַל וא"ו תי"ו מִפִּיהָ, כְּדֵי לִהְיוֹת מו"ת נָכוֹן לִפְנֵיהֶם.

He started seducing her, until it's written (Ibid.), "Wa-Tere, And she saw, the woman," [what seemed to be] a great and powerful reason, and the Otiyot Waw Taw flew and joined with Ot Mem, but Ot Mem was going up and down and not joining with them -

הִתְחִיל לְפַתּוֹתָהּ, עַד דִּכְתִיב, (שם) וַתֵּרֶא הָאִשָּׁה, בְּטַעְמָא סַגֵּי וְתַקִּיף. מְלַמֵּד, שֶׁפָּרְחוּ הָאוֹתִיּוֹת וא"ו תי"ו, וְסָלְקוּ לְהִתְחַבֵּר עִם אוֹת מ"ם. וְאוֹת מ"ם הָיְתָה עוֹלָה וְיוֹרֶדֶת, וְלֹא הָיְתָה מִתְחַבֶּרֶת עִמָּהֶם.

(daf 111b)

until she was seduced, then Waw Taw flew, four times, and surrounded Ot Mem on four sides, as it's written (Gen. 3), "WaTikach, And she took of the fruit WaTokhal and ate WaTiten and gave to her man WaTipakachna and were opened their eyes, both of them." Behold four times W' T', as they surrounded Ot Mem on four sides and with the Mem in the middle, MWT death on all sides.

[דף קיא ע"ב]   עַד שֶׁנִתְפַּתֵּת וּפָרְחוּ וא"ו תי"ו, ד' זִמְנִין, וַאֲקִיפוּ לְאוֹת מ"ם לְד' סִטְרִין. דִּכְתִיב, (בראשית, ג) וַתִּקַּח מִפִּרְיוֹ וַתֹּאכַל וַתִּתֵּן גַּם לְאִישָׁהּ וַתִּפָּקַחְנָה עֵינֵי שְׁנֵיהֶם. הָא ד' זִמְנִין ו' ת'. מְלַמֵּד, שֶׁסִּבְבוֹ לָאוֹת מ"ם לְאַרְבַּע צְדָדִין, וְהַמ"ם בָּאֶמְצַע, מָוֶת בְּכָל סִטְרִין.

As he said later (Jer. 9), "For MWT is come up in our windows" – this is S-M, who is one of the windows to heaven. And of this (Ps. 89:49), "What man is he that lives and will not see MWT?" Immediately he seized her and polluted her with impurity. The Holy Blessed One "came down to look" and Adam and his wife hid.

כמדָּבָר אַחֵר, (ירמיה, ט) כִּי עָלָה מָוֶת בַּחֲלוֹנֵינוּ. דָא סמאל, דְּאִיהוּ חַד מֵחַלּוֹנֵי שְׁמַיָא. וְעַל דָּא מִי גֶּבֶר יִחְיֶה וְלֹא יִרְאֶה מָוֶת. מִיָּד שָׁלַט בָּהּ, וְהִטִיל בָּהּ זוּהֲמָא. נָחַת קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא לְמֶיחֱמֵי, וַיִּתְחַבֵּא הָאָדָם וְאִשְׁתּוֹ.

Come and behold. Before they erred, the Shekhina was a crown on their heads, it was (constantly) for their sake resting on the world. Once they erred, as it were, its strength wore out and it departed and ruled no more. And the Holy Blessed One started mourning and said, Eikhah, what's going to be of her, she's lost rule. So too with the ruin of the Beit haMikdash, it's lost rule, and the Holy Blessed One starts eulogizing and said, Eikhah, what's going to be with her.

תָּא חֲזֵי, קוֹדֶם שֶׁחָטְאוּ, הָיְתָה הַשְּׁכִינָה עֲטָרָה עַל רָאשֵׁיהֶם, לִהְיוֹת בִּשְׁבִילָם שׁוֹרָה עַל הָעוֹלָם. כֵּיוָן שֶׁחָטְאוּ, כִּבְיָכוֹל, תַּשׁ כֹּחָהּ, וְאִסְתַּלְּקַת וְלֹא שַׁלִּיטַת. וְקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא שָׁארֵי לְקוֹנֵן, וְאָמַר אֵיכָה, מַה תְּהֵא מִינָהּ, שָׁלְטָנוּתָא אַעֲדוּ מִינָהּ. אוּף הָכָא בְּחוּרְבַּן בֵּי מַקְדְּשָׁא, שׁוּלְטָנוּתָא אַעֲדוּ, וְקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא שָׁארֵי לְמִיסְפֵּד, וְאָמַר אֵיכָה, מַה תְּהֵא עָלֶיהָ.

(end of R' Chaninai and Rabbanan's answer)

---

**However, the statement does seem more general.**  Because a woman's Neshama is rooted in the north/left/gevurah, therefore she is more susceptible to the tricks of the Yetzer haRa that come from that side.
So it seems from R' Shimon's answer about the Nachash, Zohar I:35b on Bereshit and the Hashmata (brought in the Bahir and other sefarim) related to it:

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%A7_%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%91

והנחש, רבי יצחק אמר, דא יצר הרע, רבי יהודה אמר נחש ממש, אתו לקמיה דרבי שמעון, אמר לון ודאי כלא חד, וסמא"ל הוה ואתחזי על נחש, וצולמיה דנחש דא איהו שטן, וכלא חד, תנינא בההיא שעתא נחת סמא"ל מן שמיא רכיב על נחש דא, וצולמיה הוו חמאן כל בריין, וערקן מניה, ומטו לגבי אתתא במלין, וגרימו מותא לעלמא. ודאי בחכמה אייתי סמא"ל לווטין על עלמא, וחבל אילנא קדמאה דברא קב"ה בעלמא, ומלה דא הוי תלי על סמא"ל, עד דאתא אילנא אחרא קדישא דאיהו יעקב, ונטל מניה ברכאן, דלא יתברך סמא"ל לעילא ועשו לתתא, דהא יעקב דוגמא דאדם הראשון הוה, (ושופריה) דיעקב שופריה דאדם הראשון הוה, ועל דא כמה דמנע סמא"ל ברכאן מאילנא קדמאה, הכי נמי מנע יעקב דאיהו אילנא דוגמא דאדם, מסמא"ל ברכאן מלעילא ומתתא, ויעקב דידיה נטיל בכלא, ועל דא (בראשית לב כה) ויאבק איש עמו, כתיב והנחש היה ערום, דא יצר הרע דא מלאך המות, ובגין דנחש איהו מלאך המות, גרם מותא לכל עלמא, ודא הוא רזא דכתיב (שם ו יג) קץ כל בשר בא לפני, דא הוא קצא דכל בשרא, דנטיל נשמתא לכל בשרא, ואקרי הכי:

Translation:
"Now the Serpent was..."  -- Rabbi Yitzchak said it's the Yetzer haRa. Rabbi Yehuda said it's an actual snake. They came before Rabbi Shimon and he answered them: It's precisely all one. The S-M appeared on a snake/serpent, and the form of the snake is the very Satan, and it's all one; and its image was beheld by all the creatures and they fled from it, and they approached the Woman with words and caused death for everyone.  Precisely in chokhmah, cleverness, did the S-M bring curses into the world, and destroy the first tree that the Holy Blessed One created in the world, and this thing was held by the S-M until the other Holy Tree came along, which is Yaakob, and took from him the blessings, for the S-M above and Esau below, did not retain blessing, for Yaakob was the model of Adam haRishon, (and the beauty) of Yaakob was the beauty of Adam haRishon, and therefore just as the S-M withheld blessings from the first tree, so too did Yaakob who is the tree, the model of Adam, withhold from the S-M blessings above and below, and Yaakob himself acquired everything, and therefore (Gen. 32:25), "And y'abek ("struggled" - got cast down to dust) ish (the S-M, lost the blessings he robbed) by him (Yaakob)." It's written "and the serpent was Arum, clever, naked" – this is the Yetzer haRa, this is the angel of death, and since the serpent which is the angel of death, caused death for all the world, so this is the hint of the scripture (ibid. 6:13), "Ketz kol-basar ba lefanai/ the end (awakening) of all flesh, comes before me" – this is the end of all flesh, as the Neshama is taken from all flesh, so that's how it's read.

---

Zohar I:35b 
Relevant Hashmatot (#34 in some editions)
השלמה מההשמטות (סימן ל''ד) 
**The Neshama of a male stems from the male, and the Neshamah of a female stems from the female. Namely when the Serpent pursued Chawa he said, "Since her Neshama is from the north ["hidden"; the dark side] I can seduce her quickly.** What seduction was it? He had relations with her. His [R' Shimon's] students asked him, "How did this deed happen?"
He answered: The wicked S-M make a bond with all the supernal legions to [rebel] against his Master, because the Holy Blessed One said, Have dominion over the fish of the sea [corresponding to the Serpent?] and bird of heaven [corr. to the S-M?]. He said, How can I cause him to err and drive him from before His presence? He came down with all his troops and sought out on earth a partner like him, and appointed the Serpent/snake, and it had the image/form of a camel [was arched]. He rode on it and approached the Woman. He said to her, Af-Ki, Even/Anger? Did God say do not eat from any tree of the Gan? He thought: I'll ask more with an addition, in order that she'll subtract.

She said: He has not withheld from us except from the Etz haDaat that's in the midst of the Gan; God said don’t eat of it and don't touch it lest you die. She added two things. She said, Of the fruit of the tree that's in the middle of the Gan, God said do not eat – but she was only told "from the tree."And she said, Do not touch it lest you die.

נִשְׁמַת הַזָכָר, מִן הַזָכָר. וְנִשְׁמַת הַנְקֵבָה, מִן הַנְקֵבָה. וְהַיְינוּ דְּקָא אֲזִיל נָחָשׁ בַּתְרָה דְחַוָּה. אָמַר, הוֹאִיל וְנִשְׁמָתָה מִן הַצָּפוֹן אֲסִיתֵנָה מְהֵרָה. וּמָאי הַסָתָה הֲוָה, מִשׁוּם דְּבָּא עָלֵיהּ. שָׁאֲלוּ תַּלְמִידוֹי, עוֹבָדָא הֵיכִי הֲוָה. אָמַר לָהֶם, סמ''אל הָרָשָׁע קַשָׁר עִם כָּל צְבָאוֹת מַעְלָה עַל רַבּוֹ. מִשׁוּם דְּאָמַר קוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא, וּרְדוּ בִּדְגַת הַיָּם וּבְעוֹף הַשָּׁמַיִם. אָמַר, הֵיאָךְ אוּכַל לְהַחְטִיאוֹ וּלְגָרְשׁוֹ מִלְפָנָיו. יָרַד עִם כָּל חַיָּילוֹתָיו וּבִיקֵשׁ לוֹ בָּאָרֶץ חָבֵר כְּמוֹתוֹ וּמַנוּ נָחָשׁ, וְהָיָה לוֹ דְּמוּת גָמָל. רָכָב עָלָיו וּבָא לוֹ אֵצֶל הַאִשָׁה. אָמַר לָהּ, אַף כִּי אָמַר אֱלֹהִים לא תֹאכְלוּ מִכָּל עֵץ הַגָּן. אָמַר אֲבָקֵשׁ יוֹתֵר וְאוֹסִיף, כְּדֵי שֶׁתִגְרָע הִיא. אָמְרָה, לֹא מֵנַעֲנוּ אֶלָּא מֵעֵץ הַדַּעַת אֲשֶׁר בְּתוֹךְ הַגָּן אָמַר אֱלֹהִים לֹא תֹאכְלוּ מִמֶּנּוּ וְלֹא תִּגְעוּ בּוֹ פֶּן תְּמוּתוּן. וְהוֹסִיפָה ב' דְּבָרִים, אָמְרָה מִפְּרִי הָעֵץ אֲשֶׁר בְּתוֹךְ הַגָּן אָמַר אֱלהִים לא תֹאכְלוּ, וְלֹא נֶאֱמַר לָהּ אֶלָּא מֵעֵץ הַדַּעַת. וְאָמְרָה, לא תִּגְעוּ פֶּן תְּמוּתוּן.

What did the wicked S-M do? It went and touched the tree, and the tree yelled out and said (Ps. 36:12), "Let not the foot of pride overtake me, and let not the hand of the wicked push me away/defile me (w'al-tenideini)."
Don't touch me - "And let not the hand of the wicked defile me." It went and told the Woman, Behold I touched the tree and didn't die, Af/Even/too you touch the tree and you won'd die. The Woman went and touched the tree and saw the Angel of Death coming at her. She said, Maybe now I'll be dead? And the Holy Blessed One will make him another wife and give her to Adam?! Behold I will cause him to eat with me; if we die we die both together, and if we live we live both together." And she took of its fruit and gave it to her husband too, and both their eyes were opened" and his teeth darkened. He said to her, What is is this that you've given me to eat and my teeth have gone dark, so too are blackened the teeth of all creatures! He (God) sat down in true judgement as it says, (Ps. 9:5), "You have sat as righteous judge." He called to Adam and said to him, Why did you flee from before Me? He said to Him, "I heard Your voice in the Garden, and my bones trembled and I feared for I was naked so I hid." For I am naked – from my actions; for I am naked, from my commandments; for I am naked, from my deeds, so I hid.

מָה עָשָׂה סמ''אל הָרָשָׁע הָלַךְ וְנָגַע בְּאִילָן וַהֲוָה הַאִילָן צוִֹוִחַ וְאֹמֵר (תהילים ל״ו:י״ב) אַל תְּבוֹאֵנִי רֶגֶל גָאַוָה וְיָד רְשָׁעִים אַל תְּנִידֵנִי, אַל תִּגַּע בִּי. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וְיָד רְשָׁעִים אַל תְּנִידֵנִי. הָלַךְ וְאָמַר לְאִשָׁה, הֲרֵי נָגַעְתִּי בְּאִילָן וְלָא מָתִּי, אַף אַתְּ תִּגְעִי בְּאִילָן וְלֹא תָּמוּתִי. הֲלְכָה הַאִשָׁה וְנָגְעָה בְּאִילָן וְרָאֲתָה מַלְאַךְ הַמָּוֶת בָּא כְּנֶגְדָה, אָמְרָה אוּלַי עַכְשָׁיו אֲנִי מֵתָה, וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עוֹשֶׂה לוֹ אִשָּׁה אַחֶרֶת וְנוֹתְנָה לְאָדָם הַרֵינִי גוֹרֶמֶת לוֹ שֶׁיֹאכַל עִמִי אִם נָמוּת, נָמוּת שְׁנֵינוּ. וְאִם נִחְיֶּה, נִחְיֶּה שְׁנִינוּ. וְלַקְחָה מִפִּרְיוֹ וְנָתְּנָה גַּם לְבַעְלָה, נִתְפָּקְחוּ עֵינֵי שְׁנֵיהֶם וְקָהוּ שִׁנָּיו. אָמַר לָהּ מַהוּ זֶה שְׁהֶאֵכַלְתָּנִי שֶׁקָהוּ שִׁינָי, כָּךְ קָהוּ שִׁינֵי כָּל הַבְּרִיוֹת. יָשָׁב לוֹ בְּדִין אֱמֶת שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (תהילים ט׳:ה׳) יָשַׁבְתָּ לְכִּסֵא שׁוֹפֵט צֶדֶק. קָרָא לְאָדָם וְאָמַר לוֹ, לָמָה בָּרַחְתָּ מִפָּנָי. אָמַר לוֹ, אֶת קוֹלֶךָ שָׁמָעְתִּי בַּגָּן וְרָעַדוּ עַצְמוֹתָי וָאִירָא כִּי עֵירוֹם אָנֹכִי וָאֵחָבֵא. כִּי עֵירוֹם אָנֹכִי, מִפֹּעֲלִי. כִּי עֵירוֹם אָנֹכִי, מִצִווּיִּי. כִּי עֵירוֹם אָנֹכִי, מִמַעֲשָׂי וָאֵחָבֵא.

---

A practical advice related to Eikhah and "badad": R' Nachman of Breslev's called his prime advice Hitbodedut (that a person should make a secluded personal time for talking to   H"Y).  This advice and remedy is the exact opposite of the events in the midrash on Eikhah above -- and התבדדות is spelled with BaDaD that occurs in Lam. 1:1. BaDaD - be alone with H"Y, to think and talk about what's on your heart, as you would talk to a father or friend.

Comment: (1/2) So sry I didnt get to this sooner. I havent logged back on since last time. Really amazing answer, ty! You completely answered that question so if you don't want to keep going with follow ups, ty for ur answer!! But this answer shows I could learn a lot here so I will ask some follow ups if u are interested to keep going:

Comment: (2/2) 1. Have you learned any interpretations where the Nachash in Bereshit chapter 3 can be read Yaakov/Moshiach, the holy serpent, and "Adam" as Eisav? Bereshit 3:6 doesn't say she gave to Adam, it says she gave the fruit to "her husband."  She was seduced by the Nachash so did it become her husband (wife?) already by 3:6? She also took its advice...

2. Have u learned interpretations where because the woman gave the fruit to Adam it must be referring to L-L-T not Havah?Your answer mentions the S-M alliance with L-L-T but how would the commentaries that mention she was Adam's wife fit?

Comment: @ShipBuilding Idk the answers to your other questions there but I think they're a bit outside the scope of your original question (also I don't think my answer mentioned Lili' but rather the S-M rode onto the Nachash - however since you've mentioned it check Tikunei Zohar 68a - דסמא"ל ונוקבא דיליה איהי מיתה, דאיהי לילית מלאך המות יצר הרע,). I'd probably recommend reading the Midrash and Zohar, and Tikunei Zohar, each one in order, or post another question if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you again. I just didn't want to have too many questions on the front page at once, but otherwise you're right it should be a new question.

Edit, can you please translate Tikunei Zohar 68a  דסמא"ל ונוקבא דיליה איהי מיתה, דאיהי לילית מלאך המות יצר הרע, very regrettably I dont speak Hebrew well and google translate is unreliable.

Comment: "For the S-M and his female (i.e. mate) she is Death, for she is Lili', the Angel of Death, the Yetzer haRa."